# Mix MVC 4 with ASP.NET website(not web application)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am searching for the solution whether how I can mix/add MVC 4/5 stub with my existing ASP.NET 4.0 Website(not application).

I would like to design further changes in MVC format along with whatever which is existed in my current application.

I followed [this website](https://jefferytay.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/getting-asp-net-mvc-3-to-work-with-asp-net-website-project/) but it only shows returning result content and there is no further steps on how we can add view to our website project.

When I have added my own view to the website project, it started throwing me an error as

> "Error    2   The pre-application start initialization method Start on
>   type Microsoft.Web.Helpers.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception
>   with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.."

Hence I am now having no clue, please guide on the steps where I can mix/add MVC stub to my asp.net website.

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: Try including the packages it can't find via NuGet (i.e. System.Web.Razor).

Comment: Why you want to do that? MVC is created as a `project`. Things are separated for a resaon

Comment: Nope I wanted the same state of my original application, and would like to add MVC stub in to the same.

Comment: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17800975/12597) gives the steps to have MVC with a web *site*. Controllers go in `App_Code`, views go in `Views`, you have to have all the MVC and related dlls, and also find the other `web.config` that goes in the `Views` folder.